# Shell win32 delete oldest directories (recursive)

Tags: bash, shell, recursion, directory

I need to delete the oldest folders (including their contents) from a certain path. E.g. if there are more than 10 directories, delete the oldest ones until you are below 8 directories. The log would show count of directories before/after + the filesystem before/after and what dirs were deleted.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I do not know why I got the -3, I needed support for powershell. In /bash, I know how to make it myself... :) the tag, I guess, was confusing

Answer (score 0):

You should test this first on your backup directory,

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRCOUNT="$(find . -type d -printf x | wc -c)"
if [ "$DIRCOUNT" -gt 10 ]; then
    ls -A1td */ | tail -n -8 | xargs rm -r
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

if i do not misunderstanding your intentions, below is your answer

> #! /usr/bin/env bash
>
> DIRCOUNT="$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf x | wc -c)"
>
> echo "Now you have $DIRCOUNT dirs"
>
> [[ "$DIRCOUNT" -gt 10 ]] && ls -A1td */ | tail -n $((DIRCOUNT-8)) | xargs rm -r && echo "Now you have 8 dirs"